# Как дебажить сервис на android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

Для сервиса без активити отладка по привычной кнопке не происходит. Есть на панели сверху кнопка - Attach debugger to android process, но как этим правильно пользоваться не знаю.

Comment: Все верно, после старта сервиса аттачитесь к процессу и все. Брейкпойнт не забудьте только поставить.

Comment: Да. Похоже проблема в другом. Уточню, что это не совсем сервис, а виджет. И он перестал работать как надо. Запускается, но его жизненные циклы не отрабатывают. Впрочем, это тема для другого вопроса